# Show a timed message between submit and reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "Bootstrap" form. When the user press "Submit" data is sent to file.php If the database is updated, I have an alert in that php file which echos an alert with "success". Now I'd like to alert a timed message. Not the alertbox with "OK" button. Is there some small simple code for this?

This is what I have now!

**PHP**

```
//Echo succes
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('Välkommen ".$row['usr_fname']." ".$row['usr_lname']."');";
  echo 'window.location = "../back_to_form.html"';
echo "</script>";
die();
```

Comment: Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use something like Jquery UI to fake a dialog box.  Then the reloading could happen just like you want it to.  The code would look something like this (untested, you'd need to adapt it to your app):

```
echo "<html><body>";    
echo '<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
    echo "<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">";
        echo "<p>Välkommen ".$row['usr_fname']." ".$row['usr_lname']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.settimeout(window.reload(), 5000)</script>";
echo "</body></html>";
```

More info with a better javascript example for the jquery ui message box can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants a message box that goes away when the page is reloaded rather than when the user clicks ok.  I don't know of any such built in functionality (confirm, alert, and prompt all require the user to do something before the page reloads) so my next thought was to use a faux popup like what Jquery UI provides.

Comment: I solved it by adding a landing page with timeout. But i guess maby your example works so i will set it as the answear. Thank you.

Comment: that's basically what I was suggesting, but you said you wanted a dialog box so I suggested a way to make it look like there was a dialog box without there actually being a dialog box.  The `window.settimeout(function, time)` is the thing that automatically sends you wherever you want to go after x amount of time